# Is it possible to log information into android studio from installed android application?

Tags: android

I got a requirement to dig an application and log the information into the android studio or any console. The code base is not given to me. I only get an android device with the app installed. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible when your apk file is of build type debug.

Comment: Can you explain the steps

Comment: Which kind of log you want to see? **ADB** is the tool you're looking for, you can get logcat of device or specific application from connected device. Check out here about how to do it: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: I need to find a particular sdk version installed in the app

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do is try to extract the apk from the installed application, and then reverse engineer it.

Comment: Isn't it have any solution rather than reverse engineering? How about using LogCat?

Comment: In a comment you mentioned you need to find a particular sdk version. For that, you will need to reverse engineer it.

Comment: I'm not mentioning the android sdk. A dependency is purchased and implemented in this project. That is a dev kit (SDK). I need to figure it out the version via log

Comment: You can not find that version via logcat unless it was put in there during development. If that is the case, then easiest way is to connect the phone to your laptop/pc, run android studio, and open the app. Then in the logcat area, you will be able to see the available logs